# Performing loops on list of lists of rasters

Tags: r, list, loops, raster, lapply

Need solution, help will be much appreciated.

In the following code I am creating three rasters. I then create a random `number` of point locations on this raster and I am receiving a list of three matrices with coordinates of those random locations called `samples`. I then take those locations and sample raster values to receive `samplevalues`.

What I want to change is that I want to create a set of 100,150,200 and 250 random point locations (`numberv`). So after generating these locations and receiving a list of locations, each raster will be sampled `length(numberv)`  times (in this case 4 times). As I have three rasters, then I would like to obtain a list with the first element including samplevalues obtained from my three rasters sampled 100 times each, the second with raster values sampled 150 times each, etc. The list would have `length(numberv)` elements. Then I would use those locations to obtain the raster values in these locations.

I pasted clean code for a simpler case with just one sample (1 element vector `number` used), hope it helps.

```
y <- matrix(1:300,100,3)
mv <- c(1,2,3)
rep = 200

valuematrix <- vector("list",ncol(y))

for (i in 1:ncol(y)) {
        newmatrix <- replicate(rep,y[,i])
        valuematrix[[i]] <- newmatrix
}

library(sp)
library(raster)

rasters <- setNames(lapply(valuematrix, function(x) raster(x)), 
                    paste0('raster',1:length(mv)))

# Create a loop that will sample the rasters

library(dismo)

number = 100                        # current number for random sample points number
numberv = c(100,150,200,250)        # sample number vector i want to use

# samples below will hold only coordinate values:
samples <- setNames(lapply(rasters, function(x) randomPoints(raster(x), 
                                                             n=number)), 
                    paste0('sample',1:length(mv)))

samplevalues <- vector("list",ncol(y))

for (i in 1:ncol(y)) {
        samplevalues[[i]] <- data.frame(samples[[i]],extract(rasters[[i]],
                                                             samples[[i]]))
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work?

```
# Function to sample using a given number (returns list of three)
sample.number <- function(x) {
  rps <- lapply(rasters, function(y) randomPoints(raster(y),n=x))
  setNames(rps,paste0('sample',1:length(mv)))
}

# Apply sample.number() to your numberv list
sample.set <- lapply(numberv,sample.number)

# Function to extract values from a given sample
sample.extract <- function(x) {
  lapply(1:length(x),function(y) data.frame(x[[y]],extract(rasters[[y]],x[[y]])))
}

# Apply sample.extract() to the set of samples (returns list of four lists)
sample.values <- lapply(sample.set,sample.extract)

# Access sample 1 of number 200
summary(sample.values[[3]][[1]])
```

Comment: how the sample.extract function could be restructured, so we would be looking at taking sample.set[[1]][2] to obtain raster value from rasters[1]. Then sample.set[[1]][3] and obtain raster value from rasters[2]. The result would be a list of 4 elements, each element would be a list of two items. I posted new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31585708/sampling-with-list-of-rasters-and-locations-using-function-in-r

Comment: @Anna are you set on the whole list structure for this?  it seems like the end result you want is a data frame, yes?  i think you could simplify this by simply mapping rasters to your sample points in a data frame which could include an index for each raster and number.